# funcionamiento de model::query() y $query->cursor()

Tags: laravel

Estoy usando laravel 8.

y me encontré con la edicion de un codigo, lo siguiente:

```
$query = Model::query();
foreach ($query->cursor() as $record) {
   $clientId = $record->getAttribute('USUARIO_ID');
   $response = $connector->get("api/Usuarios/{$clientId}");
   $json = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}
```

y no he entendido en su totalidad como funciona.

segun entiendo en:

```
$query = Model::query();
```

prepara ese modelo(tabla de la bd) para posteriormente hacer consultas en la bd, luego me encuentro con un ciclo:

```
foreach ($query->cursor() as $record) {
}
```

este ->cursor(), lo que hace es traerme todos los registros de la tabla, y cada registro llamarlo como record.

La siguiente linea, del registro $record, extrae el atributo 'USUARIO_ID' y lo almacena en $clientId, y luego hace una consulta a alguna api, con ese $clientId, y recibe una respuesta en json.

El cual mas adelante el usa.
Mi pregunta es:

¿Esta bien mi interpretacion?

o de que manera funciona el Model::query();
necesito comprender bien cual es el funcionamiento, ya que debo hacer unas modificaciones y este codigo ya estaba programado.
muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los modelos de Eloquent tienen un montón de métodos "formales" ('where', 'with','group' etc etc) y otro montón de sugar syntax tipo "whereIsNull", "whereCategoryName". Y todos devuelven una instancia de Query Builder (que acepta los mismos métodos) y se devuelve a sí mismo, gracias a lo cual puedes seguir encadenando más cláusulas.

Pero eso no es todo, como dicen los infomerciales. Además todos esos métodos pueden invocarse estáticamente. El primero que se invoque sobre el modelo devuelve una instancia del query builder, así que los siguientes pueden invocarse como métodos de instancia. Por ejemplo:

```
  Post::whereAuthor(1)  // ahora tengo un query builder
      ->whereIsNull('title')  // obtengo el mismo query builder
      ->withCount('comments') // idem
      ->take(10) // idem
      ->get();  // esto devuelve una colección
```

Cuando usas

```
    Post::query()
```

Es una manera de obtener la instancia del query builder sin meter ninguna clausula. Básicamente: `select * from posts`.

El uso de un cursor no devuelve un query builder sino que ejecuta la query. A diferencia de `get()` o `all()` que guardan todo el resultado en memoria, `cursor` devuelve un generador de PHP, que sólo guarda un resultado en memoria y va trayendo otro, y otro, a medida que se repite el bucle, hasta quedar vacío.

Es un poco de sintaxis extra pero muy útil cuando la cantidad de datos se hace inmanejable de la manera tradicional. De paso, me parece que el cursor impone otras limitantes para traer las relaciones mediante lazy loading, pero no me ha tocado comprobarlo.