# Quiero consultar miles de registros de SQL Server pero me restringe el límite de memoria en PHP

Tags: sql-server, php7, google-chart-api

Estoy haciendo un tablero de datos con google charts y su API visualization, no tengo mucha experiencia y estoy tratando de consultar más de 300,000 registros con PHP 7.4, pero al intentar realizar la estructura que necesita google charts para crear el dataTable, se agota la memoria. Quisiera saber si hay alternativas para poder hacer esto, como dije, no tengo mucha experiencia y estoy atorado en esta parte, he visto post que dicen que haga una paginación para mandar por lotes la información, pero no sé como hacerlo, me podrían ayudar?
Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
    public function consultar_todo_calificaciones()
{
    $data = array();
    $query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS label,
    CASE
    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'float' THEN 'number'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' THEN 'string'
    ELSE DATA_TYPE
    END AS type
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = ? ";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->tbl_calificaciones, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data['cols'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $query = "SELECT [cicloEscolar]
        ,[año]
        ,[dependencia]
        ,[Dependencia_corto]
        ,[idAreaAcademica]
        ,[areaAcademica]
        ,[nivelEducativo]
        ,[programaEducativoVersion]
        ,[PE_Corto]
        ,[asignatura]
        ,[asignaturaPeriodo]
        ,[ofertaAsignaturaGrupo]
        ,[alumnoNumeroCuenta]
        ,[alumnoPaterno]
        ,[alumnoMaterno]
        ,[alumnoNombre]
        ,[alumno_name_full]
        ,[alumnoGenero]
        ,[alumnoCohorteGeneracional]
        ,[evaluacionParcial]
        ,[calificacion]
        ,[docentePaterno]
        ,[docenteMaterno]
        ,[docenteNombre]
        ,[docente_NAME_FULL]
        ,[docenteGenero]
        ,[docenteNumeroEmpleado]
    FROM " . $this->tbl_calificaciones;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $data['rows'] = array();
    $batch_size = 40000; // 50,000 datos
    while ($registro = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $arrayValores = array();
        foreach ($registro as $key => $value) {
            if ($value) {
                array_push($arrayValores, array('v' => $value));
            } else {
                array_push($arrayValores, array($value));
            }
        }
        array_push($data['rows'], array('c' => $arrayValores));
        // Si ha alcanzado el tamaño del lote, libera memoria y continua
        if(count($data['rows']) >=  $batch_size) {
            $data['rows'] = array();
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas para optimizar:

-Si podés usar query builder va a funcionar de forma más rápida (documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries )

-Usá cursor() para evitar que se colapse la memoria, de esta forma vas tratando línea a línea los resultados (acá lo explican: [funcionamiento de model::query() y $query->cursor()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/464599/funcionamiento-de-modelquery-y-query-cursor) )

-Si tenés variables que ya no vas a usar, aplicales unset($tuVariable) para liberar memoria.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Te lo agradezco, pero query builder se puede usar sin laravel? ya que donde estoy no hacen uso de frameworks.